# Linked List adds null values automatically

Tags: java, list, jersey

I've a global static linked list in which I add data from different threads and a scheduler is configured to run every minute to process new sub list  with all the data same as the parent list
Note: **Data keeps on adding into the list from different threads so I need to get a set of data for the current processing and remove them as soon as they are processed.**
When the application runs there are null values present in the list which i never added and the values which were added are not present now.

Output something like

> A
>   
> B
>   
> C
>   
> D
>   
> E
>   
> E
>   
> FF
>   
> H
>   
> FF
>   
> SS
>   
> DD
>   
> D
>   
> null
>   
> null
>   
> null
>   
> null

The data added for the last four null values were `AA`, `BC`, `DA`, `AC`. This happens most offently when there are more than 500 request. I've tried all the ways and tried debugging in every way but even though i don't add null values it is present in the list causing me the data loss.

Even the size is same as the no of data I added.
Below is my code

Global List class

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class QueryData {
    private static List<String> queryData;
    private static QueryData instance;

    private QueryData() {
        if (queryData == null) {
            queryData = initializeQueryData();
        }
    }

    private List<String> initializeQueryData() {
        System.out.println("Initializing new query Object" + new Date());
        queryData = new LinkedList<>();
        return queryData;
    }

    public static synchronized QueryData getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new QueryData();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public List<String> getQueryData() {
        return queryData;
    }

    public boolean add(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value NULL on list QueryData");
        }
        return queryData.add(value);
    }

    public void clearQueryData() {
        initializeQueryData();
    }

}
```

Class from where my data gets added to the list

```
class Processor {

    public boolean add(String value){
        QueryData.getInstance().add(value);
    }

    public void processList(List<String> list) {

        for(String str : list) {
            System.out.println(str);
            QueryData.getInstance().getQueryData().remove(str);
        }

    }
}
```

Class which is called by the scheduler

```
class Test {

    public void callProcess() {
        List<String> processingList = new LinkedList<>();
        processingList.addAll(QueryData.getInstance().getQueryData());
        Processor p = new Processor ();
        p.processList(processingList);
    }

}
```

Jersey web service class through which data is added to it. It is called more than 10000 times in a minute.

```
@Path("/")
class Service { 
    @GET
    @Path("/add/{value}")
    public void callProcess(@PathParam("value") String value) {
        Processor p = new Processor ();
        p.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using threads, my first thought is that `LinkedList` is not thread safe.  Use one of the classes from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: do you know any similar as linkedlist ? which maintains order

Comment: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` exports a List interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ... :) It worked but further my question is, as i am using thread safe concurrent list, so do i need to declare my querydata class as singleton or it can work without any flaw if not declared as singleton.

Comment: If you want to change your question, please either update this one or just ask a new question.  I think your question might need a longer answer so it might be best to ask a new question with the new code as a sample.